# SAPUI5 / OpenUI5: Packaging

Tags: cordova, webview, sapui5, packaging, ui5-tooling

I am using OpenUI5 in my hybrid (Cordova WebView) approach. When downloading the latest OpenUI5 version I end up with a huge bunch of files and I have no clue which ones are really necessary for my purpose. It seems as if there are no precompiled files that contain everything needed for a mobile/hybrid/whatever approach.

How have you guys solved this?

Thanks and happy new year!!!

Comment: Let the UI5 Tooling do the work for you with a _self-contained_ build: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694877/5846045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you noticed the "UI5 Runtime Mobile" package at http://openui5.org/download.html#versionList ?
This is the one that is meant for such a hybrid app approach.

Such a bundle can never be 100% optimized - you might need or not need certain control libraries or themes, for example, so the following page has some more details about this package, including instructions to reduce its size:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/293eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533.html

Comment: Yes, I did but the zip still contains such a huge amount of files, especially for debugging... But I will check out the reduction suggestions that you mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to reduce the size is by removeing all the debug files as mentioned in the link . This can be easily done by searchig for *-dbg.js in Windows search and delete all.

All the debug files will be removed in one go.