# OpenUI5: Packaging - What are the best strategies when the mobile package doesn't include a functionality?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using OpenUI5 in an hybrid approach (Cordova). I have started developing my application against "openui5-runtime-1.28.17" (uncompressed approx 50 MB) and now switched to the "openui5-runtime-mobile-1.28.17" (uncompressed approx 5 MB), to reduce the app size.

Now what if I want to use things that are not included in sap.m, e.g.:

- other theming only included in openui5-runtime-1.28.17
- sap.ui.commons.HorizontalDivider (I know that's not intended to be used in a mobile scenario)
- do adaptations

I read the discussion in [SAPUI5 / OpenUI5: Packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702834/sapui5-openui5-packaging/27705379#27705379) and the corresponding links.

Is there a way to safely manually add functionality, let's say put everything in some kind of child folder?

Or is there even a way to load libraries from the device and when there is internet available to load needed libraries on the fly?
Or other strategies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should generally not use `sap.ui.commons` in combination with `sap.m` or at all in a mobile context.

Comment: I did the easy thing - removing sap.ui.commons, but still curios about such an "extension" concept...and add this also to my question